# display dynamic nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, nested

I have nested array where in array many child array no limit may 1 or 5 or 50, 100
but child array only one array

```
for example 
main array
> array
> > array
> > > array
not like that
main array
> array
> array
> > array
```

data return like that  in array
** lahore -> shadman -> Islamabad -> Faisal block **

How to create dynamically nested array in PHP

```
Data array are here
```

```
[3] => Array
        (
            [display_location_id] => 16788220061116
            [display_location_name] => Faisal block
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [display_location_id] => 19297220061159
                    [display_location_name] => Islamabad
                    [child] => Array
                        (
                            [display_location_id] => 15722120061104
                            [display_location_name] => shadman
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [display_location_id] => 13370120061129
                                    [display_location_name] => lahore
                                    [child] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example below

```
<?php

    // Inner child array
    $inner_child = ["ickey1" => "ica", "ickey2" => "icb"];

    // Child Array
    $child_array = [];
    for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){

        // Insert INNER CHILD in 3rd child
        if($i == 2){
            array_push($child_array, ["ckey1" => "ca", "ckey2" => "cb", "ckey3" => $inner_child]);
        } else{
            array_push($child_array, ["ckey1" => "ca", "ckey2" => "cb", "ckey3" => []]);
        }
    
    }

    // Main array
    $main_array = ["mkey1" => "a", "mkey2" => "b", "child"=> $child_array];
    print_r($main_array);
?>
```